# vue3 i18n undefined locale

Tags: vuejs3, i18next

i am trying to do a multilingual project, but the problem is
`redirect` returns `undefined`. is there any way to fix this?
Despite all my efforts, it still says *undefined* and it doesn't work when I type the `lang` parameter in the address bar. fixed `en.json` working

https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/installation.html

`app.js`

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'
import i18n from './i18n';
import WebsiteRouter from './Website/router';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

createApp(App)
    .use(WebsiteRouter)
    .use(i18n)
    .mount("#app");
```

`/router/index.js`

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import i18n from "../../i18n";
import routes from './routes'


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    let language = to.params.lang;
    if (!language) {
        language = 'en'
    }
    i18n.locale = language
    next()
})

export default router;
```

`routes.js`

```
import i18n from "../../i18n";

export default [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: `/${i18n.locale}`
    },
    {
        path: '/:lang',
        component: {
            render (c) { return c('router-view') }
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                name: 'home',
                component: () => import('../Views/Home.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: '/about',
                name: 'about',
                component: () => import('../Views/About.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: '/contact',
                name: 'contact',
                component: () => import('../Views/Contact.vue'),
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: using vue-i18n? https://locize.com/blog/give-vue-i18n-more-superpowers/

Comment: using i18next? https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/vue/src

Comment: I did not have a teacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
redirect: `/${i18n.globale.locale}`
```

for the redirect in routes.js

You may also try to replace:

```
i18n.locale = language
```

to:

```
i18n.globale.locale = language
```

in you router.beforeEach

Cheers :)